# set up speed tracer with ubuntu 9

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, profiler

I am having a small issue in setting up speed tracer with ubuntu.
any help (document/hints...) will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a handy tutorial the **Google Developers** put up at:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sn_3rJaexKc

And some **examples** on how to use it at :

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/speedtracer/speed-tracer-examples.html

But you're probably best off **starting** at :

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/speedtracer/get-started.html

to get your head around the concepts and features involved.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks Mark, those links are really useful. by the way, I installed the plugin, but to make it work on windows you have to add few lines at the end of chrome.exe. I am wondering how to set it up in ubuntu. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Put chrome on the upper, gray panel.
Right click the chrome icon and choose Properties.
Now append "--enable-extension-timeline-api" to the text in the Command field.

In my case the Command field contains:
/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome %U --enable-extension-timeline-api

Click Close. Restart chrome.